# Sorting userlist in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am very beginner in Laravel.
I have Laravel 5.8 in my project.

I have this code:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->string('name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('surname', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('email', 120)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            ........
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });


Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('commentable_type');
            $table->bigInteger('commentable_id');
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->char('to_stats', 1)->default(0);
            $table->tinyInteger('rating')->default(0); // 1-5
            $table->text('content');
            $table->dateTime('date_time');
            $table->ipAddress('ip');
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```

How can I show users list:

1. sort after number of comments held
2. sort after number of votes which user has (comments-> rating)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
//User model

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}

public function usersSortedByCommentCount()
{
    $users = User::with('comments')->get()->sortBy(function($user)
    {
        return $user->comments->count();
    });

    return $users;
}

public function usersSortedByRating()
{
    return User::whereHas('comments', function ($q) {
        $q->orderBy('rating', 'desc');
    })->get();
}
```

Comment: dd(User::whereHas('commentsReceived', function ($q) {
            $q->orderBy('rating', 'desc');
        })->get()); - this is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$users_sorted_by_comments = User::with('comments')->get()->sortBy(function($user){
 return $user->comments->count();
})
```

The other condition is quite similar, you need to load ratings on comments and then just sort by that count like this:

```
$users_sorted_by_ratings_on_comments = User::with('comments')->get()->sortBy(function($user){
 return $user->comments->reduce(function($carry, $comment) {
  return $carry + $comment->rating;
}, 0 );
})
```

[Laravel Collection reduce](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-reduce)

Comment: Ok, this working. How  can I sort after number of votes which user has (comments-> rating)??

Comment: I have error: Call to undefined relationship [votes] on model [App\Comment].

Comment: No I have Call to undefined relationship [ratings] on model [App\Comment].

Comment: No problem :) Now this code run, but it's not sorting correctly

Comment: What kind of output do you wish to obtain vs what does it give you?